# implicitlyWait not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have used the implicitlyWait method to set waiting time globally to find the DOM elements in selenium. I have given 100 seconds as waiting time. But in certain cases, driver hasn't found the element. It completely wait for 100 second even the DOM element loaded successfully in 10 seconds, after 100 seconds it showed as "Element not found" error. This error occurred in rare cases only. If I again run the project it working fine. Any way to handle this globally?

**Code for implicitlyWait**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pageLoadTimeOut(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Code for finding Elements**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
```

**Html Code of the particular button**

```
<input id="btnSearch" class="searchStyle"/>
```

**Note: Am using InternetExplorer Driver**

Regards,
Sunil Prabakar C

Comment: I doubt people have enough data to help you there. The HTML (and/or JS) code of the button that you fail to find would be nice, if only to make sure it should indeed be found each time.

Comment: Off topic...but why are you using an implicit wait? You're adding unnecassary execution time to your tests.

Comment: am using implicit wait, because some time my webpage taking some loading time. On that case driver was not able to find the elements. To avoid these type of issues am using implicit wait.

Comment: If it's intermittent, I would surround the call in a try/catch block, log the error message and inside the catch, I would try to run it using the `JavascriptExecutor`. Sometimes `Selenium` doesn't evaluate elements to be 'ready' to perform some action and it's doable via javascript. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use implicitWait for very static web sites. As soon as there are visual effects like animations, AJAX calls and stuff like that I had much better results with FluentWait. I still use Selenium 2.x and what I basically came up with is this routine:

```java
private void findElement(int timeout) throws Exception {
    element = null;
    if (by != null) {
        try {
            WebDriver tempDriver = getDriver();
            FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(tempDriver)
                    .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
            element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                @Override
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    List<WebElement> temp = driver.findElements(by);
                    if ((temp == null) || (temp.size() == 0)) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return temp.get(0);
                }
            });
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            logger.debug("Time Out!");
        }
    }
}
```

Where **by** is of type org.openqa.selenium.By and **element** is a field of the class where I use this method.